# Where can I find air-fare predictions?

Tags: air-travel, budget, fares

Yesterday I saw a documentary where some showed software that predicts developments in airfares. Similar to weather and traffic predictions a user would get a prediction of price developments when airfares for a specific connection are searched. Based on these prediction you could make an educated guess if you need to buy now, or better wait some time.

Since watching that documentary I have been searching for a booking site that uses this prediction feature. In the documentary they mention that such a webservice is not yet available in Europe, but since the Internet is more then Europe only, I expect to find a working example. No luck so far.

The documentary was a Dutch [documentary](http://www.uitzending.net/gemist/455/Nederland-3/De_Rekenkamer.html), where they explored the actual costs of flying an airplane from Amsterdam to London. The objective was to find a reason for the fluctuating real airfares asked.

Answer (score 7):

The only website that I know is [Farecast](http://www.farecast.com), that now seems to be called Bing Travel.

This seems to be more or less successful, as they state by themselves:

> According to a third-party audit of our predictive technology, we’re
>   about 75% accurate and on average, customers will save over $50 on a
>   typical round-trip transaction.

I never used it by myself, but friends of mine recommended it.

Comment: Clicking on farecast took me to http://www.bing.com/travel/ - is that correct?

Comment: @nsn Yes, Microsoft purchased Farecast back in 2008, and it has since been integrated directly into Bing Travel.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into [Hipmunk](http://www.hipmunk.com). This online airfare aggregator has a graphical airfare predictor. Exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 6):

If you perform a search for flights on [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com), it will sometimes show an airfare predictor in the top left-hand-corner of the results window, showing whether prices are predicted to fall or rise in the next 7 days (and therefore, whether you should purchase the ticket now or wait).

This only seems to happen when enough people have searched for that route through Kayak, so I assume they are doing the predictions based on their own historical results.

Comment: came here to say this.

Answer (score -1):

New answer for old question - check out flyr at www.getflyr.com - they currently have a beta tool that gives you buy-wait predictions on domestic flights, like Farecast/BingT used to have.

Comment: If you are connected, in any way, with that app, please disclose it in your description or any recommendations of it.

Answer (score -1):

I have used Farecast in the past with varying degrees of success. I suggest giving it a whirl. Michael Hosto

Comment: Hi and welcome. Are you in any way affiliated with the company?